# Measurement tool of QGIS working in unsaved project but disabled in saved project

Tags: qgis, geojson, measurements

The measurement tool of QGIS 3.8 is working in the unsaved project but disabled in the saved project. I unable change the measurements or the units, and the Units dialog box is grayed out.

However, when we open a new project the measurement tool is working as expected.

Why is this?

Comment: Which QGIS version? Is this the case for all of your projects? If not, what is different in this special project?

Comment: I am using 3.8 version . Measurement tool is not working in all the saved project .But if i open a new project tool is working and also i am able to change the units from meter to required unit.In saved project units dialog box is grayed out .